# What makes a place strong in the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars S06E11 - Voices*, Yoda told R2-D2 that Dagobah was strong in the Force.

High midi-chlorian counts makes a person strong in the Force, but what makes a *place* strong in the Force? Do midi-chlorians fly freely in space and a high concentration of them makes a place strong in the Force?

Or is there some kind of field line of Force originating from the Force realm?

Only canonical answers, please. EU is welcome.

Comment: I have no idea why this got down-voted - it happens at nearly every level of canon and is usually left fairly unexplained.  If anyone has a better answer than "because Force", I'ld like to hear it.

Comment: maybe...because George Lucas? :P

Comment: @joshbirk - I downvoted because parts of the question seemed unclear, especially the part about midi-chlorians flying "freely in space". I didn't understand that at all.

Comment: @Richard - gotya.  Although I'm fairly willing to let anyone be confused about midi-chlorians on nearly any level...

Comment: @SSumner - Force IS George Lucas

Comment: @joshbirk - there is a disproportionate tendency to DV this user's questions (if you check out DV stats on Data Exchange), independently of question quality; on part of some people. The best you can do is upvote the good ones.

Answer (score 13):

This is easily explained using just Episode 5 (Empire Strikes Back) as a reference.  First of all, we have Yoda's description of the Force (with my emphasis):

> For my ally is the Force.  And a powerful ally it is.  **Life creates it, makes it grow**.  Its energy surrounds us and binds us.  Luminous beings are we, not this crude matter.

Then look at Luke's observations during his approach to Dagobah (again with my emphasis):

> I'm not picking up any cities or technology.  **Massive life-form readings, though**.  There's something alive down there.

From there it's "2 + 2 = 4" stuff: Dagobah has lots of life, life creates the Force, therefore Dagobah is strong in the Force, and the answer to "what makes a place strong in the Force" is simple: "life makes a place strong in the Force".

Answer (score 11):

**It seems to take someone strong in the Force to "imbue" it**

or

**Some kind of catastrophic event to create a "wound" in the Force**

Take two of the places probably "strongest" in the force:

*[The Dark Side Cave](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Side_Cave)*

> Hundreds of years before the Clone Wars, the Jedi Minch battled and killed a powerful Bpfasshi Dark Jedi leader, and his energies absorbed into its surroundings, first tainting the passage with the dark side.

So in a way similar to becoming ghostly apparitions, powerful force users can affect places well after they are dead.

*[Mortis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mortis)*

While probably one of my least favorite arcs in *The Clone Wars*, it's an extreme example of being "strong with the force":

> Mortis was a planet enclosed in a monolith located in the remote Chrelythiumn system that was a conduit for the entire Force of the universe. Mortis became home to the Ones, a family of powerful Force users, years prior to the Clone Wars. Time was experienced differently inside the Mortis monolith than in the rest of the galaxy—standard days experienced on Mortis by Obi-Wan Kenobi, Anakin Skywalker and Ahsoka Tano were only "a moment" experienced in normal space by Captain Rex.

On the planet are specific locations attuned to dark and light side aspects.  However:

> Once the father dies, we see the world start to crumble.  It wasn't the world itself that was strong in the force - but the inhabitants.

Without a specific Force-user being responsible, a catastrophic event (like the destruction of Alderaan) could create a "[wound in the force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wound_in_the_Force)", which likewise can corrupt a location:

> Historians have theorized that the life-destroying effects of the dark side could cause a breach in the Force—especially when wielded by one as powerful as a Sith Lord. Such a hypothesis never gained universal acceptance, but it did help to explain how such potent dark side users as Darth Sidious were able to long hide their dark side affinity from the Jedi High Council. It also explained why the dwellings and tombs of the Sith such as those on Dxun, Onderon, Korriban, and Yavin 4, remained dark and corrupted locations for millennia after they were abandoned.

Although this is more or less the same concept - a place is being imbued with Force energy and seems to take a life/haunting of its own.

Answer (score 3):

### Because of the existence of Life or because The Force wills it

In current Canon, The Force exists in two ways.

1. The Cosmic Force, which is the aspect of The Force that bound everything togeather. You can think of it as the Spirit of Reality.
2. The Living Force, which is the aspect of The Force that was fed by the energy of living things. This is not a vampirical sort of thing. What I mean is that The Living Force is responsive to Life itself. This is how the Jedi have their powers and can manipulate the physical realm. This is also why mass death can be felt by force sensitives, because the extinguishment of life effects The Living Force.

So when a place is "strong in The Force" that means that there is a high concentration of Force Energies. This could be for obvious reasons, such as an overabundance of life, or an inexplicable reason, because the force does its own thing.

An example of this would be The [Wellspring of Life](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wellspring_of_Life), also known as the Force planet. This planet was a nexus of Force Energy that manifested as a planet. In *Clone Wars - S06E12 - Destiny* Yoda is told by one of the Force Priestesses that the planet is:

> ...the birthplace of what your science calls midi-chlorians, the foundation of what connects the Living Force and the Cosmic Force.
> <sub>[Serenity](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Serenity)</sub>

In plain english, The Cosmic Force manifested itself into the physical realm as The Living Force and it resulted in a planet in the center of the galaxy populated by being of pure Force.

There were other parts of the galaxy where The Force was considered to be strong. Ilum for example, where the Jedi Order got the kyber crystals for their lightsabers.

A population center does not count as enough Life to be "strong in The Force" (though it can effect The Force as evidenced by the destruction of Alderaan). An example of Life causing a location to be "strong in The Force" is [Dagobah](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dagobah/Legends) where there was so much non-indigenous life that the planet was effectively alive.

> Yup, that's it. Dagobah. […] No, I'm not gonna change my mind about this. I'm not picking up any cities or technology. Massive life-form readings, though. There's something alive down there.
> <sub>Luke Skywalker - Episode 5: The Empire Strikes Back</sub>

Qui-Gon also says that Dagobah is one of the purest places in the Galaxy within the Force, though this is unclear why at this point.